# Inject data members to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

This question is based on [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150514/custom-method-in-model-to-return-an-object)(thankfully answered).

So if in a model I have this:

```
def self.find_extended
    person = Person.find(:first)
    complete_name = person.firstname + ', ' + person.lastname
    return person
end
```

How can I inject complete name in the person object so in my controller/view I can access it by person.complete_name?

Thank you for your time,
Silviu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is creation of complete_name attribute in your Person class:

```
def complete_name
  firstname + ', ' + lastname
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be iterating over a lot of records, then using an interpolated string will be more memory-efficient.

```
def complete_name
  "#{firstname}, #{lastname}"
end
```

Using `String#+` to concatenate strings creates String objects at each step. In other words, if `firstname` is `'John'` and `lastname` is `'Doe'`, then each of these strings will exist in memory and need to be garbage-collected at some point: `'John'`, `'Doe'`, `'John, '`, and finally `'John, Doe'`. Not to mention that there are three method invocations instead of one string interpolation which is more efficiently implemented in C.

If you use the `#{}` notation, then you avoid creating the `'John, '` string. Doesn't matter when dealing with one or two records, but in large datasets used in all sorts of methods it can add up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could define:

```
attr_accessor :complete_name
```

in the person model and then just do `person.complete_name= person.firstname + ', ' + person.lastname`

Comment: Your answer was just as good for me but I found that IDBD's solution was more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Also, another quick note.  You don't need that return statement in Ruby.  The last statement in your method will be returned.